# how to add keyboard shortcut keys to milonic menu

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using milonicmenu (**http://www.milonic.com/**) for my application.
How can I put keyboard shortcuts to make the menu keyboardfriendly?

Answer (score 0):

With a library like https://github.com/blainekasten/shortcut.js It should be pretty simple, basically choose the shortcut, and bindTo one of the functions that do what you want to happen.

For example, with that library you could do

```
shortcut('o').bindsTo(openMenu);
```

Here, pressing the o button will call the openMenu function, which would in theory open your milonicmenu.